# Avoid whitespace in JSTL c:set statement

Tags: jsp, jstl, conditional-statements, whitespace, el

I have a JSP file that generates a list of LIs, where the first and the last item in the list get a special class assigned to them. I currently use the following bit for that:

```
<c:set var="liclass">
    <c:if test="${rowStatus.first}">first</c:if>
    <c:if test="${rowStatus.last}"> last</c:if>
</c:set>

<%-- not very pretty --%>
<li<c:if test="${not empty liclass}"> class="${liclass}"</c:if>>
```

The problem in this case is that, in the case when there's only one result, the class should become 'first last' (which works), but it becomes `first [...] last`, where [...] represents a bunch of whitespace that SO filters away.

It seems that `<c:set>` also takes the whitespace caused by the indentation used. I could just solve it by typing it without whitespace:

```
<c:set var="liclass"><c:if test="${rowStatus.first}">first</c:if><c:if test="${rowStatus.last}"> last</c:if></c:set>
```

But I'd prefer the readable variant. Another alternative is to pull the result through a function that removes excess whitespace.

Question: Is there an approach or technique to avoid setting whitespace like this in a `<c:set>`-tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it straight in `value` attribute with help of the conditional operator `?:`.

```
<c:set var="liclass" value="${rowStatus.first ? 'first' : ''}" />
<c:set var="liclass" value="${liclass}${rowStatus.last ? ' last' : ''}" />
```

For the not pretty `<li>` part, I'd just add

```
<c:set var="liclass" value="${empty liclass ? 'none' : liclass}" />
```

and do

```
<li class="${liclass}">
```

True, it adds a seemingly worthless `class="none"` for non-first/last elements, but who cares?

---

As to the concrete question, you can trim whitespace left by taglibs by setting the `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` attribute of the `@page` to `true`.

```
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

*(works in Servlet 2.5/JSP 2.1 containers only)*

You can also configure it at servletcontainer level. Since it's unclear which one you're using, here's just an Apache Tomcat example: in the JSP servlet entry in `Tomcat/conf/web.xml` add/edit the following initialization parameter:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Either way, I can't tell from top of head nor guarantee that it would achieve the desired effect of ending up with `first last`. You would have to give it a try yourself.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. I wasn't aware of the conditional operator (ternary operator) in EL expressions - I did search for something like that, but couldn't find it anywhere. JSP / JSTL documentation could be better. As for the worthless class - I care, ;D. I look at code with Firebug, and dead attributes make me cringe. The trimDirectiveWhitespaces attribute is another thing I was unaware of - that too will help a lot, both in this case and in other projects / cases. Thanks a lot!